# Python - Connecting to counterstrike server via socket

Tags: python, sockets, connect

I would try connect to a counterstrike server hosted on my ip through python socketing ...

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost", 27015))
```

But I would get an error

```
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

And I'm sure the server is up, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't connect, I could connect to it in game.

Comment: This works for me, so I take it it's not your code. You could try using '127.0.0.1' or a public server.

Comment: The way I'm hosting the CS server is using a cracked version of "CS Dedicated Server GUI". Before I tried using the actual IP and it would not accept the connection.

Comment: Does it work on a public CS server?

Comment: I don't think so, only LAN but shouldn't connect either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug such things you can use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to observe your Python script while it is trying to connect and compare it to a real client. You may have to listen on the "localhost" interface instead of your physical network interface to see the connection. Your server needs to do the same, so ask your OS to give you a list of bound sockets, including the IPs they are bound to (on Linux `netstat -nlp`) to check. Maybe the server needs to be configured to allow non-public IPs. Finally, make sure you got the protocol right, TCP (SOCK_STREAM) vs UDP (SOCK_DGRAM).